# Use application classes inside classes loaded through a library in open liberty

Tags: java, classloader, open-liberty, server.xml

I have a web application where this application load some classes using a library. Below is my server.xml file

```
<application id="" name="Scholar" type="ear" location="scholar.ear">
  <classloader commonLibraryRef="dynamicClassLib" />
</application>

<library id="dynamicClassLib">
  <fileset dir="${install.dir}/../dynamic/" includes="*.jar"/>
</library>
```

My Problem is when if I have used a class in my web application inside the classes which are being loaded through the library it gives the class not found exception. It seems like this is because my web application and the classes loaded through the library are loaded by two different class loaders. Is there a way where I can load all the classes using same class loader or set the parent class loader to my web application class loader?

PS:
In my web application there is a class called ClassA. And I have a ClassB in a jar file which resides in the library location. In the ClassB I am trying to use ClassA. but note that I dont have the ClassA inside the jar which resides in the library location.
So when I run the code it gives me an error while loading the ClassB saying it cannot find the ClassA.

Comment: I don't fully understand the scenario you are describing, but try changing the `commonLibraryRef` to a `privateLibraryRef` and see if that helps. If that doesn't work, please update your question with more details such as which classes are trying to be loaded from the app/library

Comment: @Andy thank you for the comment. I have updated the description with a example.

Comment: @andy-guibert is correct.  If you want the classes in the shared library to be loaded using the same the classloader as the classes in the application, then you should use a privateLibraryRef instead of a commonLibraryRef.

Comment: Hi, setting privateLibraryRef fixed the class loader issue. thank you both